# 'cannot load such file -- mongoid' with rspec with ruby 2

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

Getting this error

```
cannot load such file -- mongoid
```

when trying to run RSpec tests.

I have mongo running in another terminal (`mongod`)

with ruby 2.0

I've trying including `gem 'moped'` and `bundle`d but got the same error.

Trying to find out how to fix this error and run my tests.

This is for an open-source project that I've forked and am trying to update.

The test starts with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

begin
require 'will_paginate/mongoid' # <-- this is the issue
rescue LoadError => error
  warn "Error running Sequel specs: #{error.message}"
  mongoid_loaded = false
else
  Mongoid.database = Mongo::Connection.new.db('will_paginate_test')

  class MongoidModel
    include Mongoid::Document
  end 

  mongoid_loaded = true
end

describe...
```

I commented out `require 'will_paginate/mongoid'` but I then got `uninitialized constant Mongoid (NameError)`

Comment: Did you remember to edit your Gemfile so that it contains something like gem "mongoid", "~> 3" before you ran bundle install?